# do.call and multiple function (x)

Tags: r

I'm am currently trying to compute a species abundance index and i'm a bit stuck with the do.call command.

I have a DF built like this:

```
    YEAR    RN      DATE    NOM         SITE            LONG    SP                                     SUMNB    NB100
1   2011    RNN027  15056   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 02  310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 1   0.3225806
2   2011    RNN027  15075   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 02  310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 1   0.3225806
3   2003    RNN027  12166   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 03  330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.6060606
4   2006    RNN027  13252   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 03  330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.6060606
5   2006    RNN027  13257   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 03  330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.6060606
6   2005    RNN027  12895   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 01  540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.3703704
7   2005    RNN027  12910   ESTAGNOL    RNN027-Estagnol 01  540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758) 2   0.3703704
```

In order to calculate my index, i have to isolate every SITE/YEAR combination and take the first and last date to edit them (minus and plus 7 days).

I should be able to to do that with the following command (not working because to finished):

```
do.call(rbind, by(DF, DF[c("YEAR","SITE")], FUN = function(x) {
  tmp <- x[c(1, nrow(x)), ]
  tmpmin<-min(tmp$DATE)
  tmpmax<-max(tmp$DATE)
  tmp1<-tmp1-7
  tmp2<-tmp2+7
  return(tmp)
```

But I dont know how to complete my command to fit to what i want: I need to keep the modified dates, and add them respectivly before and after every combination of SITE/YEAR/SP. The point is to detect the first and last observation date per site for the sum of all the species, modify them as i want, and add them in the temporal repartition of each species i got (two new rows in each "chunk").

I'm am able to add a row before and after every "chunk" with the SP criteria with the following code (but the row is for now based and the first and last dates, not the dates i want):

```
do.call(rbind, by(DF, DF[c("YEAR","SITE", "SP")], FUN = function(x) {
  tmp <- x[c(1, seq(nrow(x)), nrow(x)), ]
  tmp$DATE[1] <- tmp$DATE[1] - 7
  tmp$DATE[nrow(tmp)] <- tmp$DATE[nrow(tmp)] + 7
  return(tmp)
}))
```

My question is, how can I link these two commands to succesfully add the rows containing the dates of my first command (SITE/YEAR) to the second command (SITE/YEAR/SP). I tried to add a loop in my function(x) command, as well as another do.call command, but it wasn't working.

EDIT:

@Troy: Yesterday, i succesfully add a loop in my do.call command: my goal was to subset every SITE/YEAR combination, regardless of the species. In each subset, i take the two limits of my temporal distribution for the sum of species(because i dont have that info).Then i write a row for each species with the infos i gathered in the subsets.
My loop here write me a new dataframe with N rows, for N species with the min and max dates(see below). I will further merge this dummy dataframe with my actual DF.

```
MIN<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = 9))
colnames(MIN)<-c("YEAR","RN","DATE","NOM","SITE","LONG","SP","SUMNB","NB100" )
MAX<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 100, ncol = 9))
colnames(MAX)<-c("YEAR","RN","DATE","NOM","SITE","LONG","SP","SUMNB","NB100" )
head(do.call(rbind, by(AGG100, AGG100[c("YEAR","SITE")], FUN = function(x) {

  splist<-unique(x$SP)
  lsp<-length(splist)
  for (i in 1:lsp){
  MIN$SP[i]<-as.character(splist[i])
  MIN$SITE[i]<-as.character(unique(x$SITE))
  MIN$DATE[i]<-as.character(min(x$DATE) - 7)
  MIN$RN[i]<-as.character(unique(x$RN))
  MIN$YEAR[i]<-as.character(unique(x$YEAR))
  MIN$NOM[i]<-as.character(unique(x$NOM))
  MIN$LONG[i]<-as.numeric(unique(x$LONG))
  MIN$SUMNB[i]<-0
  MIN$NB100[i]<-0
  MAX$SP[i]<-as.character(splist[i])
  MAX$SITE[i]<-as.character(unique(x$SITE))
  MAX$DATE[i]<-as.character(min(x$DATE) + 7)
  MAX$RN[i]<-as.character(unique(x$RN))
  MAX$YEAR[i]<-as.character(unique(x$YEAR))
  MAX$NOM[i]<-as.character(unique(x$NOM))
  MAX$LONG[i]<-as.numeric(unique(x$LONG))
  MAX$SUMNB[i]<-0
  MAX$NB100[i]<-0

MINMAX<- rbind(MIN,MAX)
MINMAX<-MINMAX[complete.cases(MINMAX),]  

}
return(MINMAX)
})), n=50)

YEAR     RN       DATE      NOM               SITE LONG                                                SP
1   2003 RNN027 2003-04-10 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 01  540  Brintesia circe (Fabricius, 1775)
2   2003 RNN027 2003-04-10 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 01  540  Carcharodus alceae (Esper, 1780)
3   2003 RNN027 2003-04-10 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 01  540  Celastrina argiolus (Linnaeus, 1758)
4   2003 RNN027 2003-04-10 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 01  540  Coenonympha dorus (Esper, 1782)
5   2003 RNN027 2003-04-10 ESTAGNOL RNN027-Estagnol 01  540  Coenonympha pamphilus (Linnaeus, 1758)
```

EDIT 2: It is now working, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this using `plyr` - PS if your remaining columns 6-10 are always the same for any combination of DATE/SITE, then this can be simplified further (no need for `merge()`)

```
require(plyr)

sp<-read.csv("sp.csv")
sp<-sp[,2:10] #(take out the ID numbers from csv)

mins<-ddply(sp,.(YEAR,SITE,SP),summarise,DATE=min(DATE))
mins<-merge(sp,mins,by=c("YEAR","SITE","DATE"))
mins$DATE<-mins$DATE-7

maxs<-ddply(sp,.(YEAR,SITE,SP),summarise,DATE=max(DATE))
maxs<-merge(sp,maxs,by=c("YEAR","SITE","DATE"))
maxs$DATE<-maxs$DATE+7

sp.new<-rbind(mins,sp,maxs)
sp.new[order(sp.new$DATE),]

   YEAR            SITE  DATE     RN      NOM   LONG                                     SP SUMNB     NB100
1  2003 RNN027-Estagnol 12159 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
7  2003 RNN027-Estagnol 12166 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
12 2003 RNN027-Estagnol 12173 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
2  2005 RNN027-Estagnol 12888 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 01 540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.3703704
10 2005 RNN027-Estagnol 12895 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 01 540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.3703704
11 2005 RNN027-Estagnol 12910 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 01 540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.3703704
13 2005 RNN027-Estagnol 12917 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 01 540 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.3703704
3  2006 RNN027-Estagnol 13245 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
8  2006 RNN027-Estagnol 13252 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
9  2006 RNN027-Estagnol 13257 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
14 2006 RNN027-Estagnol 13264 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 03 330 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     2 0.6060606
4  2011 RNN027-Estagnol 15049 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 02 310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     1 0.3225806
5  2011 RNN027-Estagnol 15056 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 02 310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     1 0.3225806
6  2011 RNN027-Estagnol 15075 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 02 310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     1 0.3225806
15 2011 RNN027-Estagnol 15082 RNN027 ESTAGNOL 02 310 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus,1758)     1 0.3225806
```

Comment: It's not exactly what i want. For example, 27 species have been observed in the first SITE and first YEAR (ESTAGNOL, 2003, seen in my DF). Your command detects the good dates, but merge them with the species observed at this date, for this exemple only 3 species, so 3 min rows instead of 27. I need to add two new rows ( with min and max dates) for every YEAR/SITE/SP combination. Merge do not fit to this thought.

Comment: hi @user2542995 - all you need to do if you want to isolate by SP as well, is to change the `ddply()` calls which create the min & max rows - their second argument needs to change from `.(YEAR,SITE)` to `.(YEAR,SITE,SP)` (my fault for misreading your question)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it does not fit to my question.Your command allow me to isolate the first and last DATE of each SITE/YEAR/SPECIES combination, and that is not what i want. Basically, I need to get the limits of annual observation range (first and last date of the sum of all species, thing i do not know) to create dummy data with zero obervations. I know how to get that (with do.call) and your command do it as well (min and max(DATE) for each YEAR/SITE chunk). My point is to add 2*"number of species by YEAR/SITE combination" dummy rows with the dates i isolated.

Comment: could you give an example of how you would like the result table to look? I'm having a little trouble understanding!

Comment: I updated my Question but found the solution right after. Thanks for your help!